# Send order update email programatically?

Tags: magento2, orders, email

I need to send the order status update email programatically, I tried with the class `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender` but it sends the order confirmation email, not the state update.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderCommentSender`

Comment: That was the perfect answer, thank you!